# Oracle SQL: Transfer certain records from one table to another filtering rows based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

Need to transfer certain records of some columns from `Table1` to `Table2` but filtering rows based on condition.

Lets say `Table1` looks like as shown below, has many columns in it.

```
Table1

A                 B                        C        D     E    F       G     H   ...
1    24-OCT-20 08.22.57.642000000 AM      100      xyz    1    1     
2    24-OCT-20 08.22.57.642000000 AM      100      xyz    1    0
13   25-OCT-20 05.47.52.733000000 PM      100      xyz    1    0
34   26-OCT-20 09.22.57.642000000 AM      100      xyz    1    0
25   26-OCT-20 09.25.57.642000000 AM      101      xyz    1    0
26   26-OCT-20 09.25.57.642000000 AM      101      xyz    1    1
6    26-OCT-20 09.25.57.642000000 AM      101      abc    1    1
10   26-OCT-20 09.25.57.642000000 AM      101      xyz    0    1
17   26-OCT-20 04.22.57.642000000 AM      100      xyz    1    0
18   26-OCT-20 06.22.57.642000000 AM      105      xyz    1    1
19   26-OCT-20 06.22.57.642000000 AM      105      xyz    1    0
```

In Table2, need to insert rows from Table1 based on following:

First, `select A, B, C, D, E, F from Table1 where D='xyz' and E=1;` and on the result of this query apply the following `condition` to further filter out unwanted rows:

`Condition: For same values in columns B, C, D & E in 2 different rows, if column F has 2 different values then only keep the row with greater value in column A.`

So desired output in `Table2` is shown as below:

```
Table2

A                 B                        C        D     E    F
2    24-OCT-20 08.22.57.642000000 AM      100      xyz    1    0
13   25-OCT-20 05.47.52.733000000 PM      100      xyz    1    0
34   26-OCT-20 09.22.57.642000000 AM      100      xyz    1    0
26   26-OCT-20 09.25.57.642000000 AM      101      xyz    1    1
17   26-OCT-20 04.22.57.642000000 AM      100      xyz    1    0
19   26-OCT-20 06.22.57.642000000 AM      105      xyz    1    0
```

How can this be achieved through the simplest and most efficient SQL query?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
insert into table2 (a, b, c, d, e, f)
select a, b, c, d, e, f
from (
    select t1.*,
        row_number() over(partition by b, c, d, e order by a desc) rn
    from table1 t1
    where d = 'xyz' and e = 1
) t1
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the `GROUP BY` and `KEEP` clause as follows:

```
select max(t.a) as a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e,
       max(t.f) keep (dense_rank last over order by t.a) as f
  from t
 where t.d = 'xyz' and t.e = 1
group by t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e
```